# Characterize $\frac {ax + b} {cx + d}$ as $x \to \frac {-d} c$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, rational-functions

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac {ax + b} {cx + d}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R, \neq 0$.  If $ad \neq cb$, then as $x \to \frac {-d} {c}$, then $f(x)$ approaches $+ \infty$ from one side and $- \infty$ from the other side.  (Which side is which depends on if $ad < cb$ or $ad > cb$.

What is the proper way to state *$f(x)$ approaches $+ \infty$ from one side and $- \infty$ from the other side*? Saying *$x = \frac {-d} {c}$ is an asymptote* doesn't convey that it approaches both positive and negative infinity.

And, what is the simplest way to *prove* it? Since $f$ is continuous everywhere but $\frac {-d} {c}$, and monotonic everywhere, then $f$ must be above a line $y = k$ on one side of $\frac {-d} {c}$, and jump to below that line on the other side ($k$ happens to be $\frac a c$).  But that doesn't prove that $f$ approaches $\pm \infty$ on either side.  I could work this out algebraically, but the case analysis (for positive or negative values of $a,b,c,d$) gets cumbersome, and my intuition is that there is a simple proof.
And what is the correct way to

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the function $$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ is a hyperbola so it approaches to $\pm\infty$

**To prove it**

$$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
$$=\frac{a(x+\frac{d}{c})+b-\frac{ad}{c}}{cx+d}$$
$$=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b-\frac{ad}{c}}{cx+d}$$
$$=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{\frac{b}{c}-\frac{ad}{c^2}}{x+\frac{d}{c}}$$
I hope you know that is the equation of a hyperbola. The vertical asymptote is $x=\frac{-d}{c}$ and the horizontal asymptote is $\frac{a}{c}$

Comment: Very helpful.  Is there a way to apply calculus (limits, derivatives, etc.) to the _original form_ of the equations to see this, if I hadn't realized to add and subtract in order to rewrite it? Also, what clues would tell me to rewrite the equation as you did?

Comment: @SRobertJames the technique I used to rewrite the expression is a well known method that is used in integrating rational functions like these

Comment: Also, let $f(\beta)=\frac{a}{c}$ we see that $\beta=\infty$ or $\beta=-\infty$ satisfies it, so $f(x)$ tends to both $\pm\infty$